# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver in sql sever 2008 with java 8

Tags: java

i have java 8 and sql server 2008 i know that my connection code is 100% right because same code is working on another system that have install previous version of java 8 but still i got error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` after running code please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you cannot use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. Java8 does not support it. I dont know how you got it to work the other time. You have to use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to do it.